# Перебор множеств в заданных границах

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть два целых неотрицательных числа `min` и `max`, `max > min`, а также натуральное число `n`. Необходимо получить все возможные множества вида `S={x1, ..., xn}`, где `min<x1<...<xn<max`.

Например, для `n=3, min=0, max=5` надо получить `{1,2,3}`,`{1,2,4}`, `{1,3,4}`, `{2,3,4}`.

Может в питоне есть специальная функция для этого? Если нет, то достаточно алгоритма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations
n=3 
my_min=0
my_max=5
[comb for comb in combinations(xrange(my_min+1, my_max-1), n)]
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрался

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, нашёл решение:

```
print(list(itertools.combinations(range(min+1, max-1), n)))
```